# How to install Python 3.5.1 on Wily Werewolf 15.10?

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, 15.10, python3

[Python 3.5.1](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-351/) came out on December 7th 2015 and as a beginning Python coder I would like to try the very latest version on my Ubuntu installation. At the moment Wily Werewolf 15.10 ships version 3.4 and there are some great improvements in the newest version.

I am currently running Wily Werewolf and I would be keen to hear some methods to update Python to 3.5.1.

Comment: Compile it from source...

Comment: The deadsnakes PPA does have 3.5.1 for 14.04.

Comment: D'oh! My question does look a little too close for comfort to the one muru has linked :(. Apologies....

Comment: oh well... I gave an answer anyway ;-)

Comment: @wb9688 actually this will mess your system up: I tried it and I would not suggest a newbie to install it from source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution 1: Use Docker

I would suggest that you use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/docker-engine) If you would like to test out a newer version of Python without overwriting your system Python (which it is very important that you don't, because Python 2.x and 3.x are different enough that 3.x will have breaking changes and will cause problems for packages that depend on Python 2.x)

Docker is a way to run lightweight Linux applications in a containerized way.  Think of them like a more lightweight Virtual Machine, or a [`chroot`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) with a layered union filesystem plus the management & system resource separation provided by [`cgroups`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups).

1. To install Docker, follow the [Ubuntu Installation instructions here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/).
2. To run a different version of python inside a container:

   - Pick a version from the [list here](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/)
   - Run: `docker pull python:<your_version_here>`
   - Run: `docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:<your_version_here> python your-daemon-or-script.py`

If you develop an application that you'd like to package up (optionally with dependencies) inside a container, you can create a [`Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) with build & dependency setup instructions, then build an image to distribute on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/).  Doing so is a bit beyond the scope of your question, but the [`docker-library/python` docs](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/python#create-a-dockerfile-in-your-python-app-project) give a quick summary for how to get started.

## Solution 2: Use packages from the "dead snakes" PPA

There is an [archive of old & new versions of Python here](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes/+packages?batch=75&memo=75&start=75).  To install an alternate version of Python:

1. Run: `apt-get -y install software-properties-common`
2. Run: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes`
3. Run: `sudo apt-get update`
4. Run: `sudo apt-get -y install python<your_version_here> python<your_version_here>-dev`
5. To run a Python script with one of these versions, use the alternate binary that was installed.

   - Run: `python<your_version_here> your-daemon-or-script.py`
   - For Example, with Python 3.5: `/usr/bin/python3.5 your-daemon-or-script.py`

If you need to install a specific minor version of the package, you can find the available versions with `apt-cache madison`.  For example, let's say we wanted to install a specific version of `python3.4`:

```
$ apt-cache madison python3.4
 python3.4 | 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
 python3.4 | 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
 python3.4 | 3.4.0-2ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 python3.4 | 3.4.0-2ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Sources
 python3.4 | 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main Sources
 python3.4 | 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main Sources

# To install a specific version, suffix the package name with =<version_here>
# For example:
$ apt-get -y install python3.4=3.4.0-2ubuntu1
```

Comment: does not work with `15.10 wily`. But the best answer for this topic so far.

Comment: If the "Dead Snakes" PPA does not support `15.10 wily` yet, you might want to try the `docker` solution

Comment: Just checked, and it looks like [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes/?field.series_filter=wily) does say it supports wily and appears to have packages for that distro.

Comment: Uh sorry I forgot to say, that I was talking about the solution #2. deadsnakes supports `wily` but not  `python3.5.1`.

Comment: @LittleByBlue : Ah, that makes sense... it looks like 3.5.1 is not in that PPA (at least for wily). Seeing as how [`15.10` has an EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) coming up soon this year July 2016.  You might have a better experience on the latest LTS release.

Comment: I have actually changed the question a little reflect only Wily Werewolf. Pity Wily is EOL soon enough but I would like to make the question a non-duplicate...